# How do we find the Jordan Form of matrices $A \in R^{n\times n}$ such that

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

Here are two scenarios I would like to consider.

(1) $A^2 = A$

I think that if A has the Jordan form $A = PJP^{-1}$ then we know that $A^2 = A$ implies $J^2 = J$. So we know that the diagonal elements of J are either zero or one. Because $x^2 = x$ means $x = 0$ or $1$.

But what do we know about the off diagonal elements? The claim seems to be that all the diagonal elements must be zero otherwise we won't have $J^2 = J$. Could some one explain this in detail? It is not very clear to me.

(2) $A^2 = I$.

Under this condition, we know that $J^2 = I$. Again, following the similar logic, we can have that on the diagonal of J, it must be either 1 or -1. The question is what we know about the off-diagonal element? Why do all the off diagonal elements have to be zeros?

Thank you

Comment: There are no projections which have non-trivial Jordan blocks. Just consider that any non 1x1 jordan block will grow & change if you exponentiate it. One new diagonal for each higher exponent. You can probably wikipedia on "projection" to read more about it.

Comment: For the second case: it depends on the field of your elements. If there are more complicated numbers which square to 1 then maybe other things are possible. Very very many matrices square to $I$ for example.